# Inflict damage when player is hit by minecart

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to test when a player gets hit by a minecart, then inflict damage on the person hit by the minecart based on the speed of the minecart? If testing for the speed of the minecart isn't possible, that's okay. This is as far as I got with this:

```
/testfor @e[type=MinecartRideable]
```

Obviously, this command block would be running on a constant redstone loop, and would feed into the command block testing for the player, then into the command block that does damage to the player, unfortunately, I just can't figure out how to test for the player in the same location as the minecart. Does anyone know how to do this? Is it possible? As always, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the name of a normal minecart entity is actually "MinecartRideable".

Rather than just testing for a minecart being existent, we should make the minecart do something. The /execute command allows another command to be run as a specific entity. What we want the minecart to do is /execute an /effect command that damages nearby players:

```
/execute @e[type=MinecartRideable] ~ ~ ~ /effect @p[r=0] 7 10 0 true
```

Hook that up to a clock and all minecarts will constantly be giving damage to players that they touch. It doesn't need to check if it is actually touching anyone first, because if it isn't then nobody (@p[r=0]) will be hurt so it doesn't matter.

There's no real way to test for how fast a minecart is going, so be warned that it will always give the same amount of damage, even if you are the one pushing it away from you.

*(We can technically test the speed of a minecart, but only in single values rather than a range, and its momentum tag can be decimal values.)*

Comment: What do you mean by *We can technically test the speed of a minecart, but only in single values rather than a range, and its momentum tag can be decimal values.* Could you give an example? If possible?

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms The motion NBTag is a list of doubles. Doubles can have 15 decimal places, and you can only test for a single value. For example "/testfor @e[type=MinecartRideable] {Motion:[1.0,0.0,0.0]}" would test for a minecart with EXACTLY 1m/s velocity in the direction of positive X, but it's more likely to be something like 0.8292260 which the command would not detect. Furthermore, AFAIK, you can only test for all three of the values at once, and all have to match. So there'd be no way to test speed on diagonals without billions of command blocks.

Comment: It would be nice if it was possible to test ranges of speeds, instead of the actual speed itself.

Comment: It's kinda funny, while it makes minecarts more realistic, players are now killed when they enter the minecart.

Comment: well, if you set up a line of command blocks running the command to test for speeds from x to y, then you could make it work, but there's still the issue of taking the time to get that many command blocks set up, then if you wanted damage relative to minecart speed, there'd be that many more command blocks to set up, and you'd probably need from bedrock to ground level for the area in which to set the command blocks up

Comment: @jc3833 To test for one direction, you'd need roughly 200000000000 command blocks. To test for all direction combinations you'd need 200000000000^3 command blocks, or about 8*10^33. That's more blocks than there are in the entire minecraft world (by a very long way). So yes, it probably would take a long time (several million millennia) and a lot of space (just under 10000000000000000 worlds) to set up.